# Ensuring Pandoc will capitalise 'ibid' nested at the beginning of a footnote

Tags: pandoc

Like a lot of people, I write documents in Markdown and then use Pandoc to convert to LaTeX. Pandoc renders Markdown citations in the format `[@citekey]` as `\autocite{citekey}`. I use a footnoting style based of verbose-inote. This all works well for the most part; Pandoc automatically handles multiple citations, as well as post- and pre-notes.

However, sometimes it's necessarily to nest these citations in an explicit footnote, like so:

```
^[Here is some discursive text that could go in a pre-note: [@citkey1].
But here is some more text followed by another citation that should be
in the same footnote. LaTeX won't allow nested citations of course, so
we need to use a footnote: [@citekey2].]
```

The problem is, if you open that footnote with a citation that ends up being rendered as an ibid, the `\autocite` command will leave it uncapitalised. So

```
^[[@citekey].]
```

becomes

```
\footnote{\autocite{citekey}.}
```

and renders in PDF as 'ibid'.

Assuming I'm not missing something else obvious, the solution would seem to be to replace any `\autocite` directly following `\footnote{` with `\Autocite`. My question is, what would be the best way to achieve this? Regex substitution would be pretty easy, but as far as I can tell Pandoc applies its filters directly to its native AST during the conversion.

Comment: If you can just add LaTeX commands, a `\bibsentence` would do it.

Comment: Try, instead of a footnote, a citation block: you'd have to drop the brackets in the citations and separate them by a semicolon somewhere (reflecting `biblatex`'s usage), but pandoc will put everything in an `\autocites` with the proper pre- and post-notes. E.g.: `[Here is some discursive text that could go in a pre-note: @citekey1; but here is some more text followed by another citation that should be in the same footnote. LaTeX won't allow nested citations of course, so we need to use a footnote: @citekey2.]`